# URLRewrite middleware that depends on Config dependency injection/scoped service. .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, app-startup

Struggling a little with Dependency Injection/Scoped Services with a rewrite rule class.

I have a redirects class which implements `IRule`

```
class ActivateRedirects : IRule
{        
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        // Do stuff here which relies on CoreSettings (info below)
    }
}
```

I also have a `CoreSettings` class which contains various settings, some of which are required for `ApplyRule` to work, it is initialised in `startup.cs` as follows.

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "site.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
IConfigurationRoot root = configurationBuilder.Build();             
CoreSettings s = new CoreSettings();  
services.Configure<CoreSettings>(root.GetSection("Website"));
```

So you can see above, `CoreSettings` is created as a Service, which in most cases I can consume with DI:

```
public class SomeOtherClass{
    private CoreSettings Settings;
    public SomeOtherClass(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot<CoreSettings> S)
    {
        Settings = S.Value;
    } 
    // Do stuff with Settings ....
}
```

I have read up on several pages on why I can't simply add DI to the `ActivateRedirects` Class, or explicitly pass the value in using `app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService` but everything I have read is telling what I ***can't*** do, I can't find anything to tell me what I ***can***!!

Before I am told to rewrite the code to not require `CoreSettings` for Rewriting, I can't do that because one of the rewrite rules depends on a condition which is set by a remote server via a `REST API` and what is needed in the `CoreSettings` class is the API credentials used to create the `REST Client`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do what you want. I'll assume your class is defined as follows:

```
public class ActivateRedirects : IRule
{
    private readonly CoreSettings _coreSettings;

    public ActivateRedirects(CoreSettings coreSettings)
    {
        _coreSettings = coreSettings;
    }

    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Read the configuration file, as before:

```
services.Configure<CoreSettings>(root.GetSection("Website"));
```

Next, setup your `RewriteOptions`:

```
var coreSettings = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<CoreSettings>>();
var activateRedirects = new ActivateRedirects(coreSettings.Value);

var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions();
rewriteOptions.Rules.Add(activateRedirects);

app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

If you put a breakpoint inside `ActivateRedirects`, and send a request, you'll see the `CoreSettings` field has been populated.

[image: A screenshot showing an injected setting in the ActivateRedirects class.]

### Update

I think this scenario is what `IOptionsMonitor<T>` might be designed for. It's registered as a singleton, but is notified of options changes. Change `ActivateRedirects` to:

```
public class ActivateRedirects : IRule
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<CoreSettings> _coreSettings;

    public ActivateRedirects(IOptionsMonitor<CoreSettings> coreSettings)
    {
        _coreSettings = coreSettings;
    }

    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        
    }
}
```

and change how the instance is constructed to:

```
var coreSettings = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<CoreSettings>>();
var activateRedirects = new ActivateRedirects(coreSettings);
```

For me, editing the configuration does now show updated values in `CoreSettings`. One caveat is I don't know how that notification process works. If this ends up reading the configuration directly on each request, then it will scale really poorly, so I'd advise giving it a good test first.

Comment: Thank you. That does seem to work, what I was doing wrong before was trying to use `IOptionsSnapshot` instead of `IOptions`.
However, there was a reason for that (I should have made clear in my question), which was that I would like it to pick up config changes, but I am guessing from all I have tried and that yours is the only working code method I have, that I can't really do that?!

Comment: @JamieHartnoll The problem is that `IOptions` has a lifetime of singleton, which is why it doesn't pick up changes made to your configuration. But `IOptionsSnapshot` is scoped, meaning its duration is for the request, but that's managed by the container. As the `ActivateRedirects` instance added as a rule will exist for the entirety of the application, it would keep its reference to  `IOptionsSnapshot` alive for that same duration, and so never pick up configuration changes.

Comment: Yes that's how I have now begun to understand it!
I think as I am understanding, it is because the `ActivateRedirects` instance has a lifetime of the entirety of the application, it wouldn't make sense for it to rely on something with the lifetime of a request, it could create a situation where the ever-present `ActivateRedirects` has no `CoreSettings` object to draw its dependant data?

Comment: @JamieHartnoll Almost right. With scoped instances, they are created per request by the container. But with `ActivateRedirects`, its lifetime isn't managed by the container, so it would keep a reference to the initial instance of `IOptionsSnapshot` that you pass to it, thus never providing updated configuration.

Comment: @JamieHartnoll But I have just discovered `IOptionsMonitor` which may solve your problem. Give me a couple of minutes and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JamieHartnoll Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks John. The updated code "works" but I have just realised, that determining whether the settings are actually updating or not within my app is a little more tricky than I realised, so I will have to check it out a little later on. I will report back.
I did see `IOptionsMonitor` info when Googling this before, but couldn't quite work out what it does, or how to implement it. I have a feeling it needs some kind of event hookup, but we shall see..

Comment: @JamieHartnoll No problem. Let me know what happens, either here or on a new question. I'd like to know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to do it right inside of the ApplyRule function itself.
Example

```
namespace MyNamespace {

    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;

    public class MyCustomRule : IRule {
        public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context) {
            var injectedService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMyInjectedService>();
        }
    }
}
```